# Pivot the result of pivot query, Is this possible in sql / C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, pivot, report

Below is my table with column as below

[image]

And I want to get report as below

[image]

In  this i want to get report from particular date and product within that date and its cumulative according to employee.

Is this possible in sql or C# so this can be generated in desired format.

Through pivot I have achieved for product , but further  I am unable to get result.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please add data in text format, most people prefer it as its easier to read and work upon

Comment: Based on your requirements the column grouping will have too many groups to maintain in traditional sql. Dynamic sql is possible, however, there are drawbacks. Application code in C# can do this but like dynamic sql it has drawbacks and unneeded complexities. Have you thought about using ssrs or another reporting tool for this?

Comment: Currently we are trying to do in sql itself with dynamic queries.
Also i will share the queries i have tried .

Comment: This sounds like a good example of where a dynamic cross tab is a good solution. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048/

Comment: Can you expand your Date column in the source table please

Comment: THank you Ross Bush, through SSRS i have achieved not exactly the same but similar to my solution.

Answer (score 0):

THank you everyone for your help , as told by @Ross Bush we are able to get report through SSRS. It is not same but similar to it . THe date column is been made vertical, grouped by date and been designed.